# how to write multiple insert statements in a script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 3 tables (`report,report1,report2`)

I need to insert the data into this three tables at a time by using script..(using pl/sql developer ide)

Can any one please help me to get out of this situation

Comment: You could group multiple inserts into the same transaction, and rollback the transactions if anything bad happens in any of the statements...

Comment: Any reason you can't do 3 insert statements separated by ;?

Comment: Don't confuse PL/SQL with a script file.  They are not the same thing.  You don't need to use pl/sql.  Just put 3 insert statements in a script file and execute with sqlplus or your IDE tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into report1 (...) values (...);

insert into report2 (...) values (...);

insert into report3 (...) values (...);

commit;
```